# Setting up Slimv on Windows + Vim / gVim

Tags: windows, vim

I intend to learn Common Lisp, and the book I plan to follow has suggested that GNU Emacs in conjunction with SLIME be used. However, I am not particularly fond of the way Emacs runs on Windows, and generally find Vim / gVim easier, so I was extremely happy to discover that there's basically a version of SLIME for Vim / gVim, called [Slimv](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2531).

However, I could not make it work at all. I get the following error whenever I open a `*.lisp` file:

```
Error detected while processing C:\Users\d125q\vimfiles\bundle\slimv0912\ftplugin\lisp\slimv-lisp.vim:
line 66:
E128: Function name must start with a capital or "s:" b:SlimvAutodetect( preferred )
line 80:
E133: :return not inside a function
line 85:
E133: :return not inside a function
line 89:
E133: :return not inside a function
line 195:
E117: Unknown function: SlimvInitBuffer``
```

I have Python 2.7 installed, which is the version my gVim was compiled against (as verified by `:version`). I also have [Steel Bank Common Lisp](http://www.sbcl.org/) and can run it from the command line without any problems. I do not have any Slimv-related settings in my `~\_vimrc`, although I did try setting a custom Swank command line and it resulted in the same errors.

Should I try installing Python 3, as my copy of Vim was also compiled with Python 3 support? It doesn't seem like the error is related to Python not being installed, however.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Something is not right](https://github.com/kovisoft/slimv/blob/master/ftplugin/lisp/slimv-lisp.vim#L66)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Apparently, the [latest commmit](https://github.com/kovisoft/slimv/commit/b7cbaf20699abdc103a1136245450aecf46ed089) fixes exactly that issue. I guess I'll just clone the repository instead of downloading the stable version from vim.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no buffer-local functions, which the plugin attempts to define. Before Vim version 7.4.260 that was ignored; now it's an error.

As you've found out, this has been fixed in the development version, but not yet released. A workaround would be to continue to use an older Vim version.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest Slimv at https://bitbucket.org/kovisoft/slimv/downloads/?tab=downloads would be ok!